Can I use CUDA on MacbookM4?
I'm trying to create an action detection system for my bachelor thesis.
I'm trying to integrate MMSkeleton to my project pipeline right now. https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmskeleton
For using MMSkeleton I need to Install PyTorch and torchvision (CUDA is required), which is not possible for Mac (due to my knowledge). I get this Error OSError: CUDA is required to compile MMSkeleton!
Does anyone know a way how I can overcome this obstacle?

No, you cannot, you can simply get a PC :)

that's unfortunate, thank you @Dr.Snoopy

For CUDA you need an NVidia GPU, something like a GTX 1080 or newer. Apple had a falling out with NVidia a long time ago and only shipped AMD GPUs with its Intel macs. On the M series macs the GPU is integrated with the CPU. You'll need to either run your project on a data-center (your university might have one), or get access to a PC (maybe your university has PCs available with NVidia GPUs, you might ask your supervisor).

MMSkeleton requires CUDA because they use a custom CUDA kernel for fast NMS on NVIDIA GPUs. If you really need MMSkeleton on macOS, you can try to replace their custom implementation with a pure Pytorch one and remove the dependency on CUDA.
